# I want to know this expression "get any worse" meaning

Tags: expressions

> How could this day get any worse!

I want to know the meaning of this expression "get any worse".

## TIA!

[image]

Comment: If you google **It can't get any worse** you will find pages of answers to your question.

Comment: I googled it bro.But didn't find any information which could satisfy me.If you help me it will be more grateful to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include your research. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: **(At least) it can't get any worse** is the kind of comment that someone makes - possibly to cheer him/herself up - when everything that day has gone badly. Sometimes, something else does go wrong as though fate has it in for the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the day the person is talking about is so bad, that it can't get any worse (meaning it is as bad as it can possibly be).